# how to display npx's executed binary path?

Tags: node.js, npx, yarn-workspaces

I have a yarn-workspace with different packages installed different versions of the same cli tool.

assume it is called `the-cli`

then whe I do `npx the-cli`, what option can I add to make npx print out the path for executed `the-cli`, so I know if it is picking up the right version. kind of like `which the-cli`